# Get parent firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the name of the company that the current user logged in belongs.

This is my database in Firebase:
[image]

How can I get the name of the company ?

Comment: assuming that you already have the "0" node and you want the name of the company that this node belongs. for better practice add the company name as field inside this node.

Comment: i already have, it's called "nomeEmp"

Answer (score 1):

To get that name please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("empresas").child("leixoes");

yourRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String name = (String) dataSnapshot.getKey();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i want to get the name of the company that my user that is logged in belongs.

Comment: Than you need to remodel a bit your database structure. Make the company name as a field in your `user` object. And in users node, change that id with an uniqu identifier such as UID or email address.

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```
mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://yours.firebaseio.com");
        mFirebaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.i("MainActivity", child.getKey());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "onCancelled", firebaseError.toException());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("empresas").child("leixoes").child("0");

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // to get all membros object ,then you can get company name from it by  
            Membros member= dataSnapshot.getValue(Membros.class);
            String companyName= member.getNomeEMP();

            ////// or you can get "pic" value only /////////
            String companyName= dataSnapshot.child("nomeEMP").getValue(String.class);
         }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

your pojo should be something like that

```
public class Membros {
String emailM, nomeM,tipoM,nomeEMP;
int pontM;

public String getEmailM() {
    return emailM;
}

public void setEmailM(String emailM) {
    this.emailM = emailM;
}

public String getNomeM() {
    return nomeM;
}

public void setNomeM(String nomeM) {
    this.nomeM = nomeM;
}

public String getTipoM() {
    return tipoM;
}

public void setTipoM(String tipoM) {
    this.tipoM = tipoM;
}

public String getNomeEMP() {
    return nomeEMP;
}

public void setNomeEMP(String nomeEMP) {
    this.nomeEMP = nomeEMP;
}

public int getPontM() {
    return pontM;
}

public void setPontM(int pontM) {
    this.pontM = pontM;
}
```

}